# Kotlin WebView doesn't work in app, it just opening chrome instead

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I was trying to use WebView and normally it suppose to run website in webview right?

But when I try to run my code, firstly app is opening and after a few seconds it's opening chrome.

Here's my kotlin codes

```
package com.example.webapp
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.view.KeyEvent
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.webkit.WebView
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient
    import com.example.onsbet.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
    
    
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        private lateinit var binding:ActivityMainBinding
        private val link = "https://www.mylink.com/"
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
    
            binding.webView.apply {
                loadUrl(link)
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it is opened correctly

Make sure you put the internet permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

To open links clicked by the user, provide a WebViewClient for your WebView, using setWebViewClient(). Add this line below

```
binding.webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
```

The rest of your code is correct

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.marwaeltayeb.androidkotlin.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import android.webkit.WebViewClient

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        private lateinit var binding:ActivityMainBinding
        private val link = "https://www.google.com/"
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
    
            binding.webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            binding.webView.apply {
                loadUrl(link)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, Internet connections is already given. Glad to heard it opened for you correctly. I don't know why it's opening on google chrome for me. That's kinda weird

Comment: Add this code:                 binding.webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

Comment: Try it and it will work

Comment: Thank you. It's worked! But now It seems only white screen when entered my own site link except google.com

Comment: I tried another website and it worked too. Wait until the website loads.

Comment: Write your link to try with you @Smash

Comment: Thank you buddy, I had tried but it was same white screen. So I coded with Java and now it's works :) thank you again. May I ask your contact? because I think you are better than me on mobile development and maybe you could give me some advice or smth....

Comment: You are welcome but it works in kotlin too. This is the reason I want to know if there is another issue with your link.

Comment: I do not think so if there's another issue with my link. I had used to same link with Java codes and it worked as well.

Comment: I also tried again with Kotlin link, there was a white screen again. I just cleared cache but it was same. I don't even know why